# MAMP Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: wordpress, mamp, internal-server-error

So I was trying to route in MAMP program from one WordPress project to the next. I notice the pages not loading properly. In the console I see:

3 times,  **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**

So the error is like this exactly,

```
GET http://localhost:8888/elijahink/wp-content/themes/parallextwo/style.css 
(index):151 
GET http://localhost:8888/elijahink/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.6.1 
(index):151 
GET http://localhost:8888/elijahink/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.6.1 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Now I have done anything to the files and when I last left it was working okay. So I can't recall what might have happened to it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the PHP error log file?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Oddly, the log files show me an error of a project no related to this project issue here.

Comment: Clear the error log, try again, post the result and maybe someone is able to help you debug.